# What is the best practice for serve HTML files in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, staticresource

I don't want the extension of my HTML files to show up in the address bar like index.html, login.html. Instead, I want these files to be accessed with patterns like /HOMEPAGE /LOGIN

I don't hold these files under the resources/META-INF/resources directory because I also don't want these files to be accessed directly from the address bar by typing the file name.

I could not find a built-in solution in Quarkus to meet these needs. So I followed my own solution.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Path("/LOGIN")
public String loginPage() throws IOException {
    String fullPath = PATH + "login.html";
    return Files.readString(Paths.get( fullPath ));
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right solution. Are there any best practices on Quarkus for the kind of needs I mentioned?

Comment: "*I don't hold these files under the resources/META-INF/resources directory ...*" - ["To serve static resources you must place them in the `META-INF/resources` directory of your application." (Quarkus - HTTP Reference)](https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#serving-static-resources)

Comment: @Turing85 Yes, I know but I don't want these files to be accessed directly from the address bar. That's why I hold these files in different directory.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean by "*not accessed directly from the address bar*"... the workaround you provided makes the HTML accessible from the address bar. Anyway, there is not built-in mechanism in quarkus that I know of to pull HTML resources for static serving from a different location than `META-INF/resources`.

Comment: @Turing85 " am not entirely sure what you mean" I mean that localhost:8080/index.html Instead, I only want the page to be accessed from the localhost:8080/LOGIN path

Comment: What's the dfference? Both are resource urls that return a HTML on a GET request. If the "index" is what annoys you, then rename the file to `login.html` and you can acces it through `http://localhost:8080/login.html`

Comment: @Turing85 "you can access it through http://localhost:8080/login.html" I don't want this. I want to access login.html through http://localhost:8080/LOGIN

Comment: Again: There is no default mechanism I know of in quarkus that does what you want. So writing your own resolver seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Quarkus Reactive Routes](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes), you can create a route like:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class StaticContentDeclarativeRoute {

    @Route(path = "/homepage", methods = Route.HttpMethod.GET)
    void indexContent(RoutingContext rc) {
        StaticHandler.create(FileSystemAccess.RELATIVE, "content/index.html").handle(rc);
    }

}
```

so that in this way at the URL `/homepage` you'll have the `index.html` page served.
Consider the path can also be absolute using `FileSystemAccess.ROOT`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Quarkus version 2.16 you can use the dedicated application property for setting the index page of the static files

```
quarkus.http.static-resources.index-page
```

https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference

Note: for me using quarkus-undertow dependency was blocking the property. So I had to remove it.